# Custom string Comparison in C#

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I want to implement a custom string `IComparer` in C# and apply it to a ComboBox.

**Actual Results**

If I set the `ComboBox`'s `Sorted` property to `true`, the output is :

```
A
AA
AAA
B
BB
BBB
```

**Wanted Results**

The wanted behavior of the sorting algorithm is the following (financial developers will understand why :) ) :

```
AAA
AA
A
BBB
BB
B
```

**Question**

Is it possible to do it ? Are sorting algorithms needed here ?

PS : I don't need a complete answer with code, i just need an idea of how it might be done ..

**EDIT**

This is about credit ratings. I've omitted something in my question. The ratings have to be sorted in this order :

```
XXX
XX+
XX
XX-
X+
X
X-
```

with `X in ('A','B','C')` and `'A' > 'B' > 'C'`

Comment: The documentation of ComboBox on msdn states - "The sort is case-insensitive and in alphabetically ascending order." . I think your best bet is to _insert_ the elements in the right order. (Which, you can do by calling OrderBy for example on the elements collection if it's enumerable).

Comment: Splitting the list into sublists and sorting the sublists by length, may be an option.

Comment: You should do any custom ordering either on your business layer or presentation layer, depending on situations.

Comment: I doubt it makes a difference here, but when you have a question about the way particular controls work, it's worth mentioning *which* technology you're working with (e.g. WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net)

Comment: I would suggest creating a Config Table, with fields, ConfigID, ConfigLabel, ConfigValue and SortOrder which usually all are strings and all values stays in database. Hardcoding any behaviour is bad in one way to make changes, however if these values stays in DB, its easy to manage them and and can be customized without rewriting or recompiling anything in code. I bet your AAA values are coming from DB somewhere, if not, put them in DB, and put a SortOrder column to sort it once and for all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's purely a string manipulation question.  He's just sorting a list of strings.  What he does with it isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Servy - if they were working with a control that accepted some form of comparator for its sort function to use, it would matter. And really, if controls have a `Sort` function, they ought to. But I agree that most controls I'm aware of don't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The OP specifically mentioned `IComparer`, so clearly whatever he's doing with it can leverage that interface (as I would have expected).  The whole purpose of having an interface is that you don't need to care how it's consumed when implementing it, you just meet the interface contract.

Comment: One way he might do it is to keep the `Sorted` property false, and then, if he has the values in a `string[]` called `arr`, sort that array with `Array.Sort(arr, comparer);` by specifying a custom comparer from one of the answers, and only then add the strings with `hisComboBox.Items.AddRange(arr);` like suggested by @BenjaminGruenbaum.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys. My question is more complicated than what I thought. I've edited my post.

Comment: you could do a simple workaround: add all the credit ratings in the array in the right order - there are a limited number of them - then remove all that are not used when u process the data. (sort = false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is for credit ratings, normally this is done by having a "sort order" column on the `CreditRating` class that you could use to sort the list before assigning it as the data source of the drop-down.

But, a quick workaround (based on the limited possible values) would be to sort by the first letter ascending, then by the length of the string descending:

```
if(left[0] != right[0])
    return left[0].CompareTo(right[0]);
else
    return right.Length - left.Length;
```

Another workaround if you want more control over the order is to create a list of possible values in the "right" order and then use that to sort the list:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly string[] Ratings = new [] {
        "CC","C","CCC-","CCC","CCC+",
        "B-","B","B+","BB-","BB","BB+","BBB-","BBB","BBB+",
        "A-","A","A+","AA-","AA","AA+","AAA"};
    // reverse the order so that any strings not found will be put at the end.

    public int Compare(string left, string right)
    {
       return Array.IndexOf(Ratings, right).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(Ratings, left));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works for the exact data given, it wouldn't properly sort `ABB` with `AA`.  `AA` should go first, but with your code it would go second.  You need to go through each character in both strings until you find a non-match or reach the end, *then* compare lengths.  You can't just compare the first character.

Comment: @Servy that's why I qualified it with the assumption that the values were credit ratings.  `ABB` is not a valid credit rating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DStanley. It is for credit ratings indeed. But, I've omitted something in my question, which is the rates that end with `+` or `-`. I thought about your algorithm at first, but keeping my last remark in mind, it becomes more complicated.

Comment: IMHO the "best" answer is still to define a class for Credit Rating and add an Order property to use for sorting.  However, I've added another workaround that gives you more control.

Comment: That seems to be efficient enough. Thanks @DStanley !

Answer (score 6):

Here's a mostly implemented version:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        //todo null checks on input

        var pairs = x.Zip(y, (a, b) => new { x = a, y = b });

        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            int value = pair.x.CompareTo(pair.y);
            if (value != 0)
                return value;
        }


        //if we got here then either they are the same,
        //or one starts with the other
        return y.Length.CompareTo(x.Length); //note x and y are reversed here
    }
}
```

So this uses `Zip` to get the pairs of chars from each corresponding string until one ends, returning the appropriate value if they aren't equal.  If it makes it past that then one string start with the other.  For a traditional string comparison we'd just compare the lengths in the same order as the input parameters.  Since we're essentially reversing the order based on length, note that the `x` and `y` are swapped on the last line.  That reverses the comparison logic.

Comment: It sounds like the asker has a Windows Forms `ComboBox` since he mentions the [`Sorted` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx). On that doc page it says sorting is alphabetically. So question is (also) how he might set his combo box to use your comparer. Maybe he can't use strings for "items" in his combo box? (I don't remember all details of `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The OP specifically asked for an implementation of `IComparer` that applies the specified logic.  If he's unsure how to apply that comparer to his specific case (and he's given no indication of having that problem) then that would honestly be a different question.  If you know that it's tricky to set a custom comparer and want to link/explain how to do so in a comment, then by all means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Servy. I've edited my post above and your algorithm seems to be inefficient keeping in mind what I added.

Answer (score 0):

Write the IComparer so that it takes strings but compares per character,

```
if A[0] == B[0] go to the next character.
if B[1] == null or A[1] < B[1], return A < B.
if A[1] == null or B[1] < A[1], return B < A.
if equal...continue as needed
```