# Loading in a large amount of files into C# in alpha-numeric order?

Tags: c#, file, text

I have about 1,500 .txt files of the format "filename-date" where DATE is a number. The files can easily be sorted in ascending order.

Problem is, I want to load all of these 1,500 files into one file, IN ORDER.

I know that a `foor loop` is in order, but since there are dates which are skipped I don't know how best to go about it.

Comment: examples of promatic file names? have you started said `foor` loop?

Comment: Dump the filenames into an ordered list and then go through the list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "where DATE is a number"? What does the number look like? How do we sort by this number? Do you want the files sorted by date and ignore the filename part? Or somehow else?

Comment: What do you mean there are dates that are skipped?

Comment: Do you have the files in a list? Or are you just reading all the text files in a particular directory?

Comment: How would a skipped date matter?? If they are ordered by filename and some dates have no file, so what?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the filename itself is sortable alphabetically, this would work.

1. Build a list of alphabetically sorted file paths using

   ```
   var textFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt").OrderBy(x => new string(x.ToArray()));
   ```
2. Iterate over your enumerable collection and do your processing work.

   ```
   foreach (var textFile in textFiles)
       {
           // Do work here
       }
   ```

If the file names themselves are not sortable, but just the date string at the end is, you might implement a custom comparison, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431613/custom-string-comparison-in-c-sharp).